# how to get compressed image uri for gallery Image?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-gallery, image-compression

I am working on project where there is an need for image to be compressed and need get Uri for that compressed image. The problem is when I try to compress image from gallery it is creating one more image which is compressed along with the original image with different resolution how can achieve like I should have only one image reference in gallery that is also original image not the compressed image. Please find my code snippet below with which I have tried

```
    public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);

}

private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, float degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    //img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}

private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    ExifInterface ei;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
        ei = new ExifInterface(input);
    else
        ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());

    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
}

public static Uri compressedImageUri(Uri selectedImage, Context context) {
    try {

        InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
            imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    selectedImage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        //Bitmap bmp = getResizedBitmap(original, 500);
        Bitmap rotateBitmap = rotateImageIfRequired(context, original, selectedImage);
        Bitmap bmp = getResizedBitmap(rotateBitmap, 500);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bmp, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), null);

        return Uri.parse(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Do not use `insert()` but open an output stream on 'selectedImage' and compress your bitmap to it.

Comment: `one image reference in gallery that is also original ` ? Also? You mean only? If you have two images you have two urls. If you dont want to keep the original then use my code. If that does not suit you its unclear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [`Compressor.class`](https://github.com/vijayideas/Localapp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/localapp/compressor/Compressor.java)

```
File imgFile = new File(uri.getPath());
File  compressFile = Compressor.getDefault(getContext()).compressToFile(imgFile);
```

You may need some other class so please check [`compressor`](https://github.com/vijayideas/Localapp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/localapp/compressor) package.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: what is the compression ratio for this

Comment: In `Compressor` class has fixed height and width but you can modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: Compression ratio will be same as your actual image